# How to merge USB HD partitions without data loss?

Tags: windows, ntfs, hard-drive, usb-drive

I have a WD My Passport 0748 USB3.0 HD.
It's partitioned into two NTFS partitions 31.4GB, 900GB.
I want to merge these partitions without a chance of data loss, I need it **VERY SAFELY**.
When i tried my traditional solution "Windows Disk Management" under Windows 8, it gave me this message:

> The operation you selected will convert the selected basic disk(s) to
>   dynamic disk(s). If you convert the disk(s) to dynamic, you will not
>   be able to start installed operating systems from any volume on the
>   disk(s) (except the current boot volume).

Actually, I don't know what it means, but i need to merge it **VERY SAFELY**.

Comment: You would have to take a full backup of one partition.

Comment: @user568109 one partion is enough? Is this really safe? - The 30GB is already empty but I can't help with the 900GB!

Comment: I meant just one partition. Merging requires you to unallocate one drive then extend the other drive with space freed. You are good to go.

Comment: @user568109 Thanks! but when i tried to, I got a message says: "The operation is not supported by the object." - what shall I do?

Comment: How are you trying to merge them. You have to open disk management and then delete/extend partition.

Comment: @user568109 I did as you said "open disk management and then delete/extend partition" - but stillhave this "The operation is not supported by the object" error!

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your disk management screen. Is there any other patition there ? Are both your partitions adjacent ?

Comment: @user568109 sorry I have some internet connection troubles!
http://i41.tinypic.com/2ufu3hl.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows Disk Management cannot extend a disk if it has a lower offset than the selected partition, i.e. it is on the left of selected disk. So what to do, use the disk managers discussed here:

1. [How can I extend a volume where the unallocated space is located to the LEFT of the Primary Partition in Disk Management](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/how-can-i-extend-a-volume-where-the-unallocated/777420c7-7ac1-4dd8-aa1b-759c4a6a7fe0)
2. [Windows - Adding Unallocated Drive Space "From the left"](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000678.htm)

Basically first the partition will be moved left then extended. See the steps in the second link.

Comment: Should I do the move-resize action? easier way? Again, is it safe?

Comment: Unless the process is interrupted, data will not be lost. Again if you are not sure try the software on a dummy partition on say flashdrive for testing.